# Matching model name preceeded by brand in a string

Tags: regex

**TL\DR**

Consider the following regex:

`(?<=^|\s|,)((?<=Continental|Conti)(?:\s|,)?Ts8|other)`

I am trying to use the above regex to match the `Ts8` from the below string:

`Conti Ts8 some other string`

Can someone explain to me, why this regex matches the `other` string from my input, but not the `Ts8` part?

As I interpret that regex, I am telling my script, to match these two things from my string:

- either the string **other** preceeded by a space or a comme or
- the string **Ts8**, optionally preceeded by a space or a comma, preceeded by ONE of the strings **Conti** or **Continental**, then preceeded by a space or a comma

What I would like is a regular expression, that will match on all of these inputs:

- Conti Ts8
- Continental Ts8
- my other string
- ContiTs8
- ContinentalTs8

but will not match on

- SuperContinental Ts8
- SuperContinentalTs8

**LONG VERSION**

I am trying to match model names from a string, based on a model array, containing a bunch of models. I also know the brand to these models. Some of the model names are very short (very few characters), and some contain only numbers as the model. I want to mitigate the possibility of matching false positives in this cases, by only matching them if they are preceeded with the brand of the model.

Let's take as an example, the brand named **MyBrand**. I know that this brand has two models, the model named **12** and the model named **LatestSuperBestModel**. As **LatestSuperBestModel** seems like a rather unique name, I am confortable matching it plain and simply by the model name in a string. But as **12** is just a bunch of number, I could get a large amount of false positive matches, if I match only by that. But to still be able to match that model also, I want to add the brand name to the match, because together with the brand name, **MyBrand 12** it is more likely that I will indeed match the model name from the string, instead of an arbitrary number.

Comment: You have an alternation with `other` so no surprise that it matches. There is only one assertion `(?<=^|\s|,)` and it is fulfilled.

Comment: and why doesn't my previous alteration matches also? I mean, with the example from the question, I do match the `other` string, but the `Ts8` part is not matched. If I remove the alteration, the `Ts8` part still doesn't match, meaning I get no matches at all for the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to for your cases:

```sh
(?<=^|[\h,])(?:Conti(?:nental)?[\h,]?\KTs8|other)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdkJn7/2)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `(?<=^|[\h,])`:
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `Conti(?:nental)?`:
  - `[\h,]?`: *optional match* of whitespace or a comma
  - `\K`: reset all matched info
  - `Ts8`: Match `TsB`
  - `|`: OR
  - `other`: Match `other`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: I didn't know about the `\K`. That is a game changer, thanks!